# Could full support for bounties be added to the iOS app?

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

Please can we have the ability to find and sort bounties in the iOS app?

Comment: What do you mean "find and sort" exactly? Not sure what you ask for.

Comment: Good to be able to find questions with bounties, but if there was also a sortable view, where you can sort by how big the bounty is that would be good also :-)

Comment: So you mean adding "Featured" tab like in the main site.

Comment: Yeah :-) that's what I meant!

Comment: @GrahamGold Click the That solved my problem button if it helped!

Comment: What button? I can't see one - not in the iOS app anyway... Ah, it's in the mobile site. I sense another meta search/question

Comment: This may be a duplicate but the other question has no answer either.